# How to use Wi-Fi channels above 11?

Tags: wireless

I've seen multiple reports for this bug on Ubuntu, yet no solution. In this case, the network is recognized but I can't connect.

*(No, it's not a router/driver issue.)*

Comment: Are you in the US? If so, the current standard is channels 1-11 for 802.11b/g. You will not be able to use the upper level channels. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11#Channels_and_international_compatibility for more information.

Comment: Nope, I'm not in the US.

Answer (score 5):

This might be a way to work around this:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/wireless-tools/+bug/227643/comments/3

Notably:

```
Put the following line in your /etc/modprobe.d/options
options cfg80211 ieee80211_regdom="EU"

Then reload the module iwl4965 or iwl3945 and channels 12 & 13 should work
again.
```