# Can't connect to or see my wifi ssid

Tags: 12.04, networking, drivers, atheros

Today I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop. I am unable to see my home SSID or even connect to it.

I've tried to connect as a hidden SSID but I always get prompted for authorization although my key is correct.

I'm in in Europe but my laptop is from the US. I'm not sure if that is relevant. I've read around this site and saw something that has to do with setting the channel above 11.

I'm not sure I did that correctly I did this :

[How to use Wi-Fi channels above 11?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/59310/how-to-use-wi-fi-channels-above-11)

Didn't help. I'm able to connect with cable but not via wifi either windows or linux. Other devices in my home can connect without any issues, even the kindle.

Here is the screenshot from my router :

[image]

Here is some additional info :

`lspci | grep -i network`:

```
08:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
```

`lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280`:

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002b] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company U98Z062.10 802.11bgn Wireless  Half-size Mini PCIe Card [103c:303f]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

`nm-tool`:

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------   Type:              802.11 WiFi   Driver:            ath9k   State:     disconnected   Default:           no   HW Address:        90:4C:E5:38:79:0D

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes
```

I'm not sure what to do next. Any suggestions?

Comment: You said that it connects neither on Ubuntu nor on Windows. Just check whether the WiFi/WLAN switch is ON/OFF through the keyboard. It'd be either a dedicated key on your laptop or a combo or <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Fx</kbd>. (Fx = <kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F12</kbd> depending on your Laptop make & model.)

Comment: Also take a look at: http://askubuntu.com/questions/67437/how-do-i-install-a-driver-for-an-atheros-ar9285

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure about setting channel above 11? I do run all my devices on channel 6 (no matter if bought in Europe or USA), However your WI-FI channel is set on Auto and  that should not be an issue.

Did you check if your WI-FI is hard blocked in BIOS? Got similar situation installing Mint in Europe on a Lenovo notepad bought in USA. And after endless CLI commands and installing newer drivers I was still only able to use cable to connect. Try this:

On first boot screen **enter BIOS** hit (<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>F12</kbd> - depending on your BIOS configuration)

When in BIOS **search for wireless to enable it** if disabled (Most likely chose configuration -> wireless -> enabled)

When enabled **confirm and boot normally** (probably <kbd>F10</kbd>)

Hope it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where my Compaq 610 did not see/detect the WiFi SSID. I changed the channel number to 11 under Wireless:General of my router.
And the connection reappeared and worked correctly!!